# a simple confusion in jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

```
 for(var m=1;m<=26;m++)
{

$("#letter"+m).click(function() {
    $("#letter1").attr('value', m); 
    j = 0;

    setValue(this.value, length);
    changeImage("#img");
})
}
```

in the above code , all goes exactly as expected but the only problem is: when I click letter1,letter2 and so on the value on letter1 should be 1,2 and so on respectively  as I expect

```
$("#letter1").attr('value', m);
```

but the value is always 27 on clicking any button, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16805590)'s right about the reason (by the time the handler executes, `m` has long been `27`), but I'd suggest a different solution.

If we use a different variable that does not change with the loop, you will get the expected behavior. The easiest way to do this as JavaScript has function scope is to use a function:

```
function attachHandler(m) {
    // Since it's an argument, the m in here will initially take the value of the
    // m outside, but it's not the same variable, so it won't change as the
    // outside m changes.
    $("#letter"+m).click(function() {
        $("#letter1").attr('value', m); 
        j = 0;
        setValue(this.value, length);
        changeImage("#img");
    });
}
for(var m=1;m<=26;m++) {
    attachHandler(m);
}
```

A common idiom for this is to use an immediately-invoked function expression:

```
for(var m = 1; m <= 26; m++) {
    (function(m) {
        $("#letter"+m).click(function() {
            $("#letter1").attr('value', m); 
            j = 0;
            setValue(this.value, length);
            changeImage("#img");
        });
    })(m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time the `click` handlers execute, the loop has long finished and `m` was assigned the value of 27 - on which the loop terminated.

```
for(var m=1;m<=26;m++)
{
  $("#letter"+m).attr("valueOfM", m);
  $("#letter"+m).click(function() {
    $("#letter1").attr('value', $(this).attr("valueOfM")); 
    j = 0;

    setValue(this.value, length);
    changeImage("#img");
  });
}
```

Comment: oh i see , what may be the solution then?

Answer (score 0):

your loop runs 26 times each time incrementing m the each time, so m ends up at 27. Maybe what you want is to set a different var to 1 and use that

Comment: oh i see , what may be the solution then?